# ZeroMQ: flow control in Publish Subscribe sockets

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq

I am trying to bench-mark the performance of ZeroMQ publish-subscribe archetype implemented in **`PUB/SUB`** socket scheme, and have quite a problem. I am publishing messages as fast as possible and then subscribing and processing it as fast as possible.

**Publisher:**

```
import zmq
import time
MAX = 100000
context = zmq.Context()
pub_sock = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub_sock.bind("ipc:///home/pub")

time.sleep(1)
var1 = 1
starttime = time.time()
while var1 != MAX+1:
    pub_sock.send_string('Msg: dummy message')
    var1 += 1

totaltime = time.time() - starttime

print "total time: %s" % totaltime
print "Message/second: %s" % float(MAX/totaltime)
```

**Subscriber:**

```
import zmq
import time
MAX = 100000
context = zmq.Context()
sub_sock = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub_sock.connect("ipc:///home/pub")
sub_sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'Msg')

try:
    rawData = sub_sock.recv_string()
    starttime = time.time()
    counter = 1
    while counter != MAX:
        rawData = sub_sock.recv_string()
        counter += 1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


totaltime = time.time() - starttime
print "total time: %s" % totaltime
if sum == MAX:
    print "all messages recieved"
else:
    print "data has been lost"
```

The problem is sometimes the Publisher is much faster than the subscriber and the queue will reach the High-Water-Mark and I will loose messages. If that happens, the subscriber loop will never exit and then I will need to use keyboard interrupt to end it and to find out number of messages received.

**I don't want to increase the HWM** because, the default of 1000 is what I would like to use for the actual software as well, so would prefer to keep it at 1000 during benchmarking.

I have looked at the built-in performance testing script of ZMQ (`local_thr`, `remote_thr` scripts inside **`perf`** folders), but they are written in C (**I want python script performance test**), and also they use **`PUSH-PULL`** sockets, not `PUB-SUB` sockets. The `PUSH-PULL` sockets become blocking once the HWM is reached, so the ZMQ performance testing scripts don't run into the problem of message getting lost due to dropping. It just slows down the process.

I would like to have similar behaviour but with **`PUB-SUB`** sockets.

Apparently, there is no provision in ZeroMQ to change the behaviour of `PUB-SUB` to blocking when HWM is reached.

**Is there an alternative means to achieve flow control here?**

One related question:
If I run 1 publisher and 1 subscriber, messages rarely get lost.
When I ran 1 publisher and 3 subscriber (all subscriber subscribe to the same topic), around 10% of messages were lost (on all subscribers). I tried to throttle down the publisher by introducing dummy statements inside the loop, and in-order to achieve no-message-loss on all subscribers, I had to throttle down by almost 1/3. `Is this normal?` It appears like the messages are being delivered to subscribers one at a time (as opposed to in parallel), and hence taking thrice as much time.

Thank you.

Comment: The PUB socket must send to each SUB socket individually because it's not using multi-cast (PGM/EPGM).  The message must be addressed individually at the publisher.  So far as I know it doesn't use any internal multi-threading to push those messages out in parallel.

Comment: A publisher is not meant to care about its subscribers nor synchronize with them. You want some synchronization, so use `REQ-REP` or `PUSH-PULL` instead (or in addition).